# Reverse engineering of mixed tiles of QR code

Tags: windows-7, imagemagick, qr-code

I have 25 tiles, each 94x94px, of previously splitted QR code (470x470px). I need to recover QR code by combining all possible tiles into one image. 3 tiles suppose to be "anchors" or big squares located at NW, NE and SW corners. Therefore we have remaining 22 tiles with unknown position. How to generate all possible combinations using ImageMagick?

**UPDATE:**

My first approach is to generate text file (which later will be fed to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#miff) as input) with all combinations, taking into account static squares (NW, NE and SW corners). I struggle to understand how to interact with IM command line interface. How to pass text file with commands to tell IM what to do?

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks Kurt Pfeifle for clarification. Indeed it would take enormous amount of time and resources to go this way. Maybe I can do it in old fashioned way. The way all puzzles get solved: print out, cut manually to 25 tiles, and combine it. I know this may sound ridiculous on SO but that is only possible solution at the moment I can think of. If I decide to go this way I nee to know the rules how QR code is generated. I know about location of big squares at 3 sides. What else do I have to know?

Maybe there is more elegant way to do it? (Please don't suggest split to tiles and import to Photoshop. Tried. Wasted a lot of time.)

**UPDATE 3**

Here is the QR code and tiles I split it using ImageMagick.

[QR code and tiles](http://dropcanvas.com/pwbfb)

**UPDATE 4**

I suspect that QR have been rotated 180 degrees CW because big squares has white space which most likely located at NE, SW and SE corners. I am not sure about if rotation to each tile was applied but as far as I worked with them in Photoshop, at least 7 aligned without rotation (*not 100% sure though)....

**UPDATE 5**

As I understand writing algorithm would be a bit tricky but much more helpful than doing brute-force search. The constraints should be like:
    1. the width and height of lines of 2 connected blocks must correspond to some range of px (ex.: cannot connect 2 blocks if it produces 1px line or dot)

**UPDATE 6**

Thank You, Sir! I started from wrong assumption about corner elements, that was my problem leading me to nowhere. After I got idea how corner elements should be placed at other is a few minutes work in Photoshop. Although even with wrong placement of corner blocks I got to point where around 10 elements was aligned right into one big block. Now I challenge to come up with algorithm to align these tile completely automatically based on set of rules (Python+ ImageMagick's MagickWand API)

Comment: Can you tell us which size the individual 25 tiles have? Are they only 7x7, or are they bigger?

Comment: Also, do you know the orientation of each of the tiles (other than the 3 corners)? If not, you have 4 *"degrees of freedom"* to arrange each each of the remaining 22 tiles -- that multi-multi-multi-plies the already immense variety even more!

Comment: QR puzzle is 470x470px this gives 25 tiles with size 94x94px each

Comment: Sorry, I can no longer quote by heart the general rules of QR codes. I remember, they were not easy to discover visually. Read up some of the basics in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) -- look especially at **[this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:QR_Code_Structure_Example_3.svg)** for structural information such as *version* and *structure* information, *alignment* and *timing* patterns, all of which have to appear at certain positions...

Comment: What's the file size of your 25 tiles in *Bytes*? Are they JPEG or PNG, or... ?

Comment: BTW, how did it happen that the 25 tiles got separated? Are you just trying to get your school homework done? Is this a riddle or a real puzzle?

Comment: @Kurt Pfeiflem, I mentioned that I separated it using imageMagick. It's not homework although I would love to have that kind of challenges while I was studying ;)

Comment: I saw the mention of the separation by ImageMagick. But at the time I thought this was to just create a look-alike for demo purposes, and your 'real' QR code had a somehow different life cycle story...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task ahead is a special case of a general mathematical field, *combinatorics*. (Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, and I'm not a mathematician either. So I'm not sure if this is the correct English technical term for the field.)

Combinatorics has a few generally proofed rules about how many combinations/orders of N distinct objects are possible if there are N slots for the objects and each object must be placed into one slot at a time.

Take the most simple example first: 1 element, 1 slot. There is only one option.

Next, two elements: a + b, and two slots: 1 + 2. There are two options:

1. *a,b*
2. *b,a*.

Three elements: a + b + c, and three slots: 1 + 2 + 3. There are now six options:

1. *a,b,c*
2. *a,c,b*
3. *b,a,c*
4. *b,c,a*
5. *c,a,b*
6. *c,b,a*.

This general rule (which can easily be proven by applying the generic mathematical proof method of *[complete induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction))* is:

> **"For *`N`* elements, there are *`N!`* different arrangements."**

where `N!` denotes the *factorial of N*, meaning to be the product of all positive integers less than or equal to `N`. For example:

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120
```

As you can see the factorial function is growing rather fast...   :-)

Your general requirement is equivalent to put 22 tiles into 22 positions. A quick -- *har!,har!* :) -- calculation shows that

> 22! = 1.124.000.727.777.607.680.000

`22!` is (coincidentally!) 22 digits long. It also contains 4 trailing zeroes (which constitute 18.18% of the whole number).

So I propose some job sharing between us:

1. ***Your part*** is this: please start to generate or write the *"textfile with all the combinations"* you suggested in your question.
2. ***My part***: I will, by the time you're done with it, be able to provide you a simple shell script to generate all the QR codes you are looking at.

But before you start to write your textfile with all the combinations, please consider this:

1. My script will read the text file as input line by line.
2. Each line will run trigger 1 ImageMagick command to generate the appropriate QR code image.
3. So you need to provide a text file that holds 1.124.000.727.777.607.680.000 different lines.
4. Since all your text file's lines need to be different from each other (otherwise they'll represent dublettes of two or more combinations), they need a minimum of 23 bytes (22 bytes to name the 22 different tile names -- you can be lazy and name them as single letters -- plus an EOL/CR/NL character).
5. Hence, your text file size is a minimum of *2.4728016 * 10<sup>22</sup>* Bytes long.
6. So make sure, before you start writing the file, that your computer has enough hard disk space to hold that file.
7. The disk needs to be able to hold *23 billion* of TeraBytes (for your text file alone)! That is 23 [ZetaBytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettabyte) *(How much storage, again, is the NSA creating for itself in its [new data center in Bluffdale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_Data_Center)?)*
8. Oh, and while you're at it, when shopping for large harddisks: maybe you can also consider the space that we'll need for all the QR code images which my ImageMagick script will generate...

I guess you have already a strategy how to select the one (or the few) correct sample(s) out of the totality of eventually re-stitched together QR code you are looking for.

---

### Update

I do not want to be totally mean to you.  :-)

Maybe you have some other means to reduce the number of 22 "uncertain" tiles... In that case the following hints will help you to arrange all 25 tiles as a 5x5 grid into one image.

#### Create a 5x5 montage of 25 different images

ImageMagick has the `montage` command. This allows you to stitch together different images into lines, columns or grids as one single image.

1. **Create 25 different images first.**
   (These will represent 25 different values of gray, as 100x100 pixels of gray patches.)

   ```
    for i in $(seq -w 1 25); do
      saturation="$(( $(echo x${i} | sed 's#x0*##') * 10 ))"
      color="srgb(${saturation},${saturation},${saturation})"

      convert          \
        -size 100x100  \
         xc:"${color}" \
         graypatch_${i}.png
     done
   ```
2. **Tile these 25 images into two different grids.**
   (The first grid will be ordered along the gray values, the second one will be random.)

   ```
    montage            \
      -geometry +1+1   \
       graypatch_*.png \
       grid1.png

    montage            \
      -geometry +1+1   \
       $(ls -1 graypatch_*.png | sort -R) \
       grid2.png
   ```

The `-geometry +1+1` parameters are not really required. I only put them in in order to get the small white space into the grid...

The first montage command uses the 25 gray patches as input in the order the shell expands the **`*`** wildcard. This order will be alphabetical. Alphabetical order will at the same time match an order of increasing darkness of the gray value, due to the algorithm I chose for the creation of the original 25 patches.

This is the resulting `grid1.png`:

[image: grid1.png]

The first grid is indeed ordered according to the "25 Shades of Grey" (heh,heh!).

This is the resulting `grid2.png`:

[image: grid2.png]

The trick here was to use `sort -R`. (***Note***, that the `-R` for random sorting is only for GNU sort.)

#### Putting 3 patches into a fixed positions (NW, NE and SW corners)

As the previous examples demonstrate:

1. If you have 25 images, `montage` will automatically create a 5x5 grid.
2. The individual images will be positioned in the order they appear on the command line: left-to-right first, then top-to-bottom.

Assuming, you name the 3 tiles with fixed positions as:

- `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` and `3.jpg`

Assuming, you name the 22 tiles with "uncertain" positions as:

- `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...u,v,w}.jpg`

Then:

1. To position `1.jpg` into the ***NW*** corner, put it as the ***first*** image on the command line.
2. To position `2.jpg` into the ***NE*** corner, put it as the ***fifth*** image on the command line.
3. To position `1.jpg` into the ***SW*** corner, put it as the ***twentyfirst*** image on the command line.

The rest of your 22 JPEGs you can place into the other positions as you like.

But remember: you have 1.124.000.727.777.607.680.000 different choices for these...  :-)

---

### Update 2

The OP has added some more info (though not all that was requested):

- Each individual tile has 94x94 pixels.
- The complete QR-Code has 470x470 pixels.

His idea to *"solve it as all puzzles are solved: print out, cut manually to 25 tiles, and combine it" does not look too promising to me...

However, here is some structural information which may help to fix a few of the 22 undetermined tiles into a specific location (or rule them out for other places when puzzling). It is a 45x45 QR code example (originally provided on [Wikipedia as "QR Code Structure Example 3" by Bobmath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#mediaviewer/File:QR_Code_Structure_Example_3.svg) -  Licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0):

[image: QR Structural Information]

Maybe the OP has a chance to put correct and/or plausible *version* and *format* information patterns in place, as well as *alignment* and *timing* patterns (on top of the 3 *position* patterns he already knows)...

The most promising strategy to me seems go forward in the following order:

1. Identify these six tiles which contain the *alignment* patterns first
2. Find out how many choices you have to place these two (out of the previously identified six) alignment pattern tiles which go in between the 3 *position* pattern tiles (remember: they need to provide a valid *timing* pattern too)
3. Can you pay your hard disk storage now?  :-)

Trivia fact: in a 470x470 module QR code there should appear `7 * 7 - 3 = 49 -3 = 46` alignment patterns.

---

### Update 3

After OP provided a [ZIP file](http://dropcanvas.com/pwbfb) with the 5 individual tiles inside, under the filenames `tile_0.png`, `tile_1.png`, ... `tile_24.png`, it now looks that the job is much easier than I originally reckoned. What I had not taken into account (what also was not clear from the OP's question, or what I made wrong assumptions about):

1. The original QR code contains the full *"quite zone"*.
2. The 25 separated tiles are not cut sharply along the QR *module* borders, but right through the *meat* of these modules.

These two facts together make it much more easy to piece together the puzzle he posed.

To give everyone an idea of how the 25 pieces look like, I've created a grid of them, with the following characteristics:

1. Each tile is annotated with the name of its originating file.
2. Each tile is separated 3 pixels apart from the next rows and next columns.
3. There is a colored background to clearly show the (white) *"quiet zone"* strips.

(***Update*** -- unfortunately, the OP edited my illustration and masked 9 out of 25 tiles with a big black square, so you won't be able to see what it looked like any more. But if you are clever... :) Here is the result :

[image: Illustration of 25 tiles]

Looking at these tiles, taking into account the white "quiet zone" edge strips where they are visible, the following things can be stated right away:

Assuming each tile's orientation is still the original one...

1. **`tile_24.png`** belongs into the top right corner of the final QR code image.
2. **`tile_11.png`** belongs into the top left corner of the final QR code image.
3. **`tile_6.png`** belongs into the bottom left corner of the final QR code image.
4. **`tile_4.png`** belongs into the bottom right corner of the final QR code image.
5. 12 tiles, **`tile_8.png`**, **`tile_9.png`**, **`tile_10.png`**, **`tile_13.png`**, **`tile_14.png`**, **`tile_15.png`**, **`tile_16.png`**, **`tile_17.png`**, **`tile_18.png`**, **`tile_19.png`**,  **`tile_22.png`** and **`tile_23.png`**, due to their *quiet zone* edge strip belong to an edge position.
6. There are even more restrictions (such as "**`tile_17.png`**, **`tile_22.png`** and **`tile_13.png`** belong to the top edge, with 17 probably at second position, next to 11")...
7. ...but I won't solve the complete puzzle here.

### Update 4

Hmmm... just staring at above image for about 5 minutes and taking some more notes, I came up with this:

```
 11  17  22  13  24
 18  21   7   2   9
 14   0  20   3  10
 15   5   1  12  23
  6  16   8  19   4
```

That's my last hint in this matter.  :-)

---

<sub>I don't even know what the award is  **:-(**</sub>

Comment: Interesting, can you try this with the QR I shared? :)

Comment: @RCola: Nope -- that's your job :-)

Comment: @RCola: BTW, you didn't mention (or did I overlook it?) that your 25 tiles do include the "quite zone" for the edge tiles. Also, for some reason I assumed that your *"94x94px"* and *"470x470px"* facts meant a QR code with 470x470 QR *modules*. --  Now that you offer an example zip, where the 25 tiles are ***NOT*** separated sharply along the QR module borders, but they cut right through their meat, it is much easier to puzzle it together! (I'm doing the homework of pupils and students only if they *pay* me, though :-) ...

Comment: -- (continued:) ...Just identify these tiles, which have one or two completely white edge strips -- these are part of the "quiet zone" and belong to one of the borders of the final QR code...

Comment: Hey, it was interesting working on this problem together ;) If you will be around the area (QR code gave you a hint) I will get you a coffee ;)

Comment: AWARD IS WAITING YOU! You know what I am talking about! ;)

Comment: I bet you used some kind of graphical editor to put all those tiles together! Am I correct? (:

Comment: @RCola: no I didn't use a graphical editor. I used the above text representations in Vim overwrite mode: started with the four corners, then filling out the empty edges one by one after identifying these tiles which could only possibly fit the joints. During the I kept a few short lists inside the same text file with *"not yet assigned"* numbers and *"candidate for top edge"*, *"candidate for left edge"* etc.

Comment: @RCola: thanks for offering the coffee -- now waiting for an opportunity to be "around the area"  :-)

Comment: @RCola: hey, RCola -- you've now hidden some of the tiles' contents, supposedly *"due to the private nature of their contents"*??? What's private about this? After all, you did publish a link to the ZIP file with all the individual tiles?!?

Comment: Yes, I did because usually I would present sample data instead of real one, but in this case I had difficulties to generate sample QR. Archive is no longer accessible. This is one of the last stages of multilevel challenge. I think people who created this would not be happy to see the solution online because of too much beers they have to give out to "winners" ;)

Comment: It seems unlikely that tile 15 could be on the left border as it doesn't have a clear `quiet zone`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: you're being fooled by the fact that OP in retrospective swapped the image and masked various tiles with a big black square, amongst them tile 15.

Comment: Booo :-( That's a shame - Ich wollte aber damit spielen.