# Algorithm to solve QR puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm, imagemagick

I am building algorithm to automatically solve / rebuild QR code from number of tiles of equal size.

My approach:

1. Get one of 3 side squares : Position squares
2. Get the width of outer black border somehow using ImageMagic

[image]

*Which for given example is 14px x 14px* (UPDATE: it might be 13px by 13px)

3. Set it as a constant: BLOCK_SIZE
4. Start cycle matching VALID tiles and already compiled block of QR code

*VALID is : unmatched  AND not any of 3 corner tiles (big black squares)*

4.1. Render all possible combinations of already compiled qr block AND 1 random valid tile from until the match found

4.2 If match found (tile can be placed by one of sides of already compiled/combined block of QR code) then record match

4.3 Match conditions:

There are no BLACK areas which have width and height conform to this equation:

```
AREA_HEIGHT % BLOCK_SIZE  == 0  && AREA_WIDTH % BLOCK_SIZE  == 0
```

Now there are some implementation complications arise:

1. How to implement algorithm which matches a tile to tile (OR already compiled/combined block of QR code)?

I think ImageMagic can solve it.
**The goal is to get original QR code.**

[Example QR tiles in ZIP](http://dropcanvas.com/FWY36dq7p9m2F9)

**UPDATE**

As I see the solution narrows down to make ImageMagick scan and find if two tiles can be put together without breaking rules of QR code. Algorithm should try to put 2 tiles side by side and scan border areas. The trick is to measure width and height of black lines/blocks of joined tiles. How to do it?

**UPDATE2**

Comparison if tiles match using 2 columns of width 1px is not enough in some cases. For example, both algorithms will join this 2 tiles into:

**VALID**
[image: **VALID**]

and

**INVALID**
[image: **INVALID**]

As you seen in **INVALID**, there is part of 2nd tile (the one on the right) was removed as denoited by red arrows, but since comparison done by 1px  - algorithm doesn't care abuot this case. Hance invalid QR.

**UPDATE3**

http://dropcanvas.com/6bl6v

Archive containing:

- invalid join.png
- valid join.png
- src1.png
- src2-invalid.png
- src2-valid.png
- invalid.png

If your algorith will join `src1.png` and `src2-invalid.png` it fails. It's about if joined tiles will produce valid QR in the end. I hope you got my point.

**UPDATE4**

I will accept an answer after I test and get correct solution. It might take some time....

**UPDATE 5 : TESTING**

Everything seems correct with Mark's solution.

Comment: I had a quick look at the image you linked to in your question. Your statement in point 2. is ***NOT*** true. The given example's outer black border is 13 pixels wide, not 14 pixels. Also, after I solved ***[your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207087/reverse-engineering-of-mixed-tiles-of-qr-code)***, I'll not even try to do this one unless you set up a really huge bounty...   :-)

Comment: No tiles were rotated. About point 2 you might be right. I used PageRuler Chrome extension to get measurement. What made u sure it's 13px x 13px?

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle, I don't mind starting bounty because it's interesting for me. What numbers are we talking about? )

Comment: PS. I have solution already. I am just interested in algorithm so solve this current puzzle. Next I will try to generalize the algorithm to wider variety of types of QR puzzles.

Comment: Here is a list of the privileges associated with the respective reputation levels: **[http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)**

Comment: I still don't get your argument after update 3, sorry. In any case, my algorithm would do what you assume it would. First of all, each tile has at least two other tiles to connect to (not just one, as you assume). My algorithm takes that into account. The solution for the final QR code image is deterministic and correct.

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle, Please tell, will your algorithm join `src1.png` and `src2-invalid.png` if you put only this 2 files in folder? Or just give script output in this case. I am interested in the results. I would have done it by myself but I need it asap. )

Comment: My algorithm would have sorted out both, `src2-invalid.png` and `src2-valid.png`, as invalid, because their shapes are not square (they are only 80x68 pixels, not 80x80 pixels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a try at this as follows.

1. Go through all PNGs and extract their North, East, South and West edges. If any PNG has two white edges, tell user it is a corner-piece. If any PNG has one white edge, tell user it is an edge-piece.
2. Go through all edge pieces. Convert each one into a PBM format file and strip the headers and new lines so that it will just be an 80 digit long string, each digit a zero or a one for black or white. Calculate checksum of the string and then reverse the string to account for the image being flipped or rotated and then recalculate the checksum. Print out the checksums and pipe into `sort` so that matching edges come out together.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove any edges generated in previous runs of this script
rm *_[NESW]*png 2> /dev/null
rm *_[NESW]*txt 2> /dev/null

DEBUG=1

# Process all PNGs
for f in *.png; do

   echo "Processing $f ..."

   # Get basename of image
   base=$(basename -s .png "$f")

   # Get width and height - not actually used at the moment
   read w h <<< $(identify -format "%w %h" "$f")
   [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "   width:$w"
   [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "   height:$h"

   # Extract North edge
   convert "$f" +repage -crop x1+0+0 +repage "${base}_N.png"
   [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "   North edge extracted"

   # Extract East edge
   convert "$f" +repage -gravity east -crop 1x+0+0 -rotate 90 +repage "${base}_E.png"
   [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "   East edge extracted"

   # Extract South edge
   convert "$f" +repage -gravity south -crop x1+0+0 +repage "${base}_S.png"
   [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "   South edge extracted"

   # Extract West edge
   convert "$f" +repage -gravity west -crop 1x+0+0 -rotate 90 +repage "${base}_W.png"
   [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "   West edge extracted"

   # Test if corner or edge piece
   n=0
   for edge in N E S W; do
      name="${base}_${edge}.png"
      min=$(identify -format "%[min]" "$name")
      if [ $min -gt 0 ]; then
         ((n++))
         e=$name
      fi
   done
   [ $n -eq 1 ] && echo "   $e is edge-piece"
   [ $n -eq 2 ] && echo "   $name is corner-piece"
done

EDITED FROM HERE ---
# Now convert all edges to text, forwards and backwards to allow rotation
for f in *_[NESW].png; do
   base=$(basename -s png "$f")
   # Convert to PBM format, remove 2 header lines and make into one line string
   str=$(convert "$f" -compress none pbm: | sed "1,2d" | tr -d "\n ")
   echo "$str:$f"
   str=$(rev <<< $str)
   echo "$str:$f (flipped)"
done | sort
```

**Partial Output (to save space)**

```
Processing 4555-18116-29.png ...
   width:80
   height:80
   North edge extracted
   East edge extracted
   South edge extracted
   West edge extracted
   4555-18116-29_S.png is edge-piece
Processing 5004-10810-17642.png ...
   width:80
   height:80
   North edge extracted
   East edge extracted
   South edge extracted
   West edge extracted
   5004-10810-17642_W.png is corner-piece
Processing 5167-27533-24066.png ...
   width:80
   height:80
   North edge extracted
   East edge extracted
   South edge extracted
   West edge extracted
Processing 5774-30645-16062.png ...
   width:80
   height:80
   North edge extracted
   East edge extracted
   South edge extracted
   West edge extracted
0a7bb6f610c0f1a6da4794ea7ae00f00:10297-13918-3702_W.png (flipped)
0a7bb6f610c0f1a6da4794ea7ae00f00:11976-7751-26756_E.png (flipped)   <-- this image is identical to the one above as the md5 checksum on the left is the same
0ce419e072c7ea5d14e3525d4afe150e:11976-7751-26756_W.png (flipped)
0ce419e072c7ea5d14e3525d4afe150e:13858-18007-13070_E.png (flipped)  <-- this image is identical to the one above as the md5 checksum on the left is the same
0ce419e072c7ea5d14e3525d4afe150e:20056-20936-29071_S.png
0ce419e072c7ea5d14e3525d4afe150e:24658-20374-23042_E.png (flipped)
0ce419e072c7ea5d14e3525d4afe150e:24658-20374-23042_S.png
0ce419e072c7ea5d14e3525d4afe150e:27206-10104-18226_N.png
0ce419e072c7ea5d14e3525d4afe150e:30261-16558-25650_N.png
```

**Notes**

Note that this assumes you have not tiled the images EXACTLY between the individual "fields" of the QR codes as identified by @YvesDaoust.

Also, some parts of the code are redundant, as I was developing the algorithm at the same time as the code - I think the `-rotates` and `+repages` are unnecessary and things could be optimised more but there was no indicated need for speed in the question. The North, East, South and West edges could be extracted in a single IM command too. The width and height that I obtained are unused so could be removed from the code.

Also, the md5 checksum is not really necessary, `sort` will place `0001110001010110` next to another string the same anyway without needing to checksum them.

Per request, I am uploading the complete solution. I removed the md5 checksum stuff as it was unnecessary. You will need to scroll right to see the filenames below:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:10297-13918-3702_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:10297-13918-3702_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:11976-7751-26756_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:11976-7751-26756_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:13858-18007-13070_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:13858-18007-13070_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:16369-21469-8252_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:16369-21469-8252_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:18056-16294-30425_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:18056-16294-30425_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:20021-11440-20836_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:20021-11440-20836_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:20056-20936-29071_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:20056-20936-29071_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:21875-14159-1067_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:21875-14159-1067_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:22806-3380-17484_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:22806-3380-17484_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24426-18830-5627_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24426-18830-5627_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24658-20374-23042_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24658-20374-23042_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24658-20374-23042_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24658-20374-23042_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:27206-10104-18226_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:27206-10104-18226_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:27206-10104-18226_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:27206-10104-18226_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:30261-16558-25650_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:30261-16558-25650_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:31250-3578-9750_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:31250-3578-9750_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:31250-3578-9750_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:31250-3578-9750_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:4555-18116-29_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:4555-18116-29_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:5004-10810-17642_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:5004-10810-17642_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:5004-10810-17642_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:5004-10810-17642_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111100:21875-14159-1067_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111100:5004-10810-17642_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111:28824-13023-24184_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111:5774-30645-16062_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111:13789-10513-4721_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111:32078-14314-1511_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:11976-7751-26756_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:13858-18007-13070_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:20056-20936-29071_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:24658-20374-23042_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:24658-20374-23042_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:27206-10104-18226_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:30261-16558-25650_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000:31250-3578-9750_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000:16369-21469-8252_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000:18056-16294-30425_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000:27206-10104-18226_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000:31250-3578-9750_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111:10297-13918-3702_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111:28824-13023-24184_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000000000:20021-11440-20836_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000000000:26507-21853-11958_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111100000:15816-4564-31665_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111100000:17636-24599-1877_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111:21875-14159-1067_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111:26507-21853-11958_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111110000000000000000000:13789-10513-4721_S.png
00000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111110000000000000000000:17636-24599-1877_N.png
00000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000001111111111:22161-18187-20222_W.png
00000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000001111111111:28824-13023-24184_E.png
00000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000:15816-4564-31665_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000:26507-21853-11958_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000:20056-20936-29071_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000:22806-3380-17484_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000:18056-16294-30425_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000:4555-18116-29_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000011:16369-21469-8252_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000011:24426-18830-5627_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000:10297-13918-3702_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000:11976-7751-26756_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111111111111111:13789-10513-4721_N.png
00000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111111111111111:5774-30645-16062_S.png
00000000000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000:15816-4564-31665_N.png
00000000000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000:32078-14314-1511_S.png
00000000000000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111111111100000000:13789-10513-4721_W.png (flipped)
00000000000000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111111111100000000:22806-3380-17484_E.png (flipped)
00000000000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000:13789-10513-4721_S.png (flipped)
00000000000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000:17636-24599-1877_N.png (flipped)
00000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111:22161-18187-20222_S.png
00000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111:5167-27533-24066_N.png
00000000000000000011111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000:20021-11440-20836_N.png
00000000000000000011111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000:26507-21853-11958_S.png
00000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000:10297-13918-3702_W.png
00000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000:11976-7751-26756_E.png
00000000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:16369-21469-8252_N.png (flipped)
00000000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:18056-16294-30425_W.png
00000000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:27206-10104-18226_E.png
00000000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:31250-3578-9750_S.png (flipped)
00000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111111:21875-14159-1067_N.png (flipped)
00000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111111:24426-18830-5627_S.png (flipped)
00000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100:20021-11440-20836_W.png
00000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100:4555-18116-29_E.png
00000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000:18056-16294-30425_E.png
00000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000:4555-18116-29_W.png
00000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100:20021-11440-20836_E.png
00000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100:5004-10810-17642_W.png
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:11976-7751-26756_W.png (flipped)
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:13858-18007-13070_E.png (flipped)
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:20056-20936-29071_S.png
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24658-20374-23042_E.png (flipped)
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:24658-20374-23042_S.png
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:27206-10104-18226_N.png
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:30261-16558-25650_N.png
00000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:31250-3578-9750_W.png (flipped)
00000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111000:22806-3380-17484_N.png
00000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111000:30261-16558-25650_S.png
00000000000011111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111111111:10297-13918-3702_E.png (flipped)
00000000000011111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111111111:13858-18007-13070_W.png (flipped)
00000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000:20056-20936-29071_N.png
00000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000:22806-3380-17484_S.png
00000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111100000:17636-24599-1877_W.png
00000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111100000:20056-20936-29071_E.png
00000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000111111111111111111:13858-18007-13070_S.png (flipped)
00000000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000111111111111111111:22161-18187-20222_N.png (flipped)
00000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000:15816-4564-31665_E.png
00000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000:26507-21853-11958_W.png
00000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000:30261-16558-25650_E.png (flipped)
00000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111000000:5774-30645-16062_W.png (flipped)
00000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111000000:17636-24599-1877_S.png
00000000001111111111111000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111000000:18056-16294-30425_N.png
00000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000001111111111111000000:11976-7751-26756_S.png
00000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000001111111111111000000:5774-30645-16062_N.png
00000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111110000000000000111111:16369-21469-8252_W.png (flipped)
00000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111110000000000000111111:22161-18187-20222_E.png (flipped)
00000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000:15816-4564-31665_N.png (flipped)
00000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000:32078-14314-1511_S.png (flipped)
00000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111110000000:15816-4564-31665_S.png (flipped)
00000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111110000000:4555-18116-29_N.png (flipped)
00000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000:32078-14314-1511_E.png
00000000111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000:5167-27533-24066_W.png
00000000111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111:28824-13023-24184_S.png (flipped)
00000000111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111:32078-14314-1511_N.png (flipped)
00000000111111111111111111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000:13789-10513-4721_W.png
00000000111111111111111111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000:22806-3380-17484_E.png
00000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000:32078-14314-1511_E.png (flipped)
00000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000:5167-27533-24066_W.png (flipped)
00000001111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000:15816-4564-31665_S.png
00000001111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000:4555-18116-29_N.png
00000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000:30261-16558-25650_E.png
00000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000:5774-30645-16062_W.png
00000011111111111110000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000:11976-7751-26756_S.png (flipped)
00000011111111111110000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000:5774-30645-16062_N.png (flipped)
00000011111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000:17636-24599-1877_S.png (flipped)
00000011111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000:18056-16294-30425_N.png (flipped)
00000111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000:17636-24599-1877_W.png (flipped)
00000111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111100000000000:20056-20936-29071_E.png (flipped)
00000111111111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111:26507-21853-11958_N.png
00000111111111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111:5167-27533-24066_S.png
00000111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000:15816-4564-31665_W.png (flipped)
00000111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000:17636-24599-1877_E.png (flipped)
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000:22806-3380-17484_N.png (flipped)
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000:30261-16558-25650_S.png (flipped)
00111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:21875-14159-1067_S.png
00111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:5004-10810-17642_N.png
00111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000:20021-11440-20836_W.png (flipped)
00111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000:4555-18116-29_E.png (flipped)
00111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000:20021-11440-20836_E.png (flipped)
00111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000:5004-10810-17642_W.png (flipped)
11000000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000:16369-21469-8252_S.png
11000000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000000:24426-18830-5627_N.png
11111100000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000:16369-21469-8252_W.png
11111100000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000:22161-18187-20222_E.png
11111110000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111100000000:28824-13023-24184_S.png
11111110000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111100000000:32078-14314-1511_N.png
11111110000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111:24426-18830-5627_W.png (flipped)
11111110000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111:5167-27533-24066_E.png (flipped)
11111111110000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000:22161-18187-20222_W.png (flipped)
11111111110000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000000000000000000000:28824-13023-24184_E.png (flipped)
11111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000:21875-14159-1067_N.png
11111111111111100000000000001111111111111000000000000011111111111110000000000000:24426-18830-5627_S.png
11111111111111111100000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000:13858-18007-13070_S.png
11111111111111111100000000000011111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000:22161-18187-20222_N.png
11111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:28824-13023-24184_W.png
11111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:5774-30645-16062_E.png
11111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:13789-10513-4721_E.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:32078-14314-1511_W.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111000000000000000000:22161-18187-20222_S.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000111111111111000000000000000000:5167-27533-24066_N.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111111000000000000:10297-13918-3702_E.png
11111111111111111111111111111000000000000011111111111111111111111111000000000000:13858-18007-13070_W.png
11111111111111111111111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000:13789-10513-4721_N.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111110000000000000111111111111100000000000000000000000:5774-30645-16062_S.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:10297-13918-3702_S.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:28824-13023-24184_N.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000111111111111111111111111100000:26507-21853-11958_N.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000111111111111111111111111100000:5167-27533-24066_S.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000:21875-14159-1067_W.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000:26507-21853-11958_E.png (flipped)
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000001111111:24426-18830-5627_W.png
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000001111111:5167-27533-24066_E.png
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach! :) I have installed Cygwin and ImageMagic as described here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=25910&start=30#p113836. Can I reproduce this solution with that?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to port to Windows BATCH file or java or any other language. Most of it is blank spaces and comments anyway. All the calls to ImageMagick will have the same parameters in any language too. It is only a couple of loops through selected files with some ImageMagick commands that you have and some `if` statements and `echo/print` commands.

Comment: Can You upload full log output which suppose to be solution. I hope solution data can be saved in more compact format so it could be fed into ImageMagic to join all tiles.

Comment: @RCola I have uploaded it per your request.

Comment: As soon as I can reproduce the solution I will approve the answer. Many thanks!!! PS. `The goal is to get original QR code.`. If You have script to join tiles from your program's output it would make the answer complete.

Comment: I would wait a little... @KurtPfeifle is extremely capable and may come up with something better - he's good! :-)

Comment: Indeed, he is, there is no doubt! He helped me a lot in previous challenge related to QR ocde :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce your solution. I even tried running your script as administrator but nothing changes.

Comment: Mmmm... you are running on `Cygwin` which isn't 100% compatible with the Mac I use. You only seem to have posted part of the error message. Try running the script with the `-xv` switches turned on so you can see what is happening... `bash -xv mark.sh` or however you do that in `cygwin`.

Comment: I'll be back online in 2 hours or so & show you then.

Comment: OK. 1. I don't understand `base=$(basename -s .png "$f")`. 2. Would be better to place generated files in  new folder but not the same as tiles. 3. `sort` would fit better

Comment: 4. where the results is stored? is there a file which can be easily parsed to generate original QR?

Comment: I have edited the final loop of the code to remove the need for md5 checksumming, which, as I pointed out in the comment, is not strictly necessary. Of course you can change the output directory for the files if you wish - do as you please. If you prefer `sort` then feel free to use that.

Comment: The results are not stored. But you can run `mark.sh > results.txt` if you want to. Like Kurt's answer, it doesn't re-assemble the entire QR code for you - it just tells you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what kind of syntax it is `$(basename -s .png "$f")`? maybe documentation link... ?

Comment: The syntax `$()` means to take the result of running the command inside the parentheses. The `basename` command in there strips all leading directory paths down to the filename without the directory path - the `-s .png` then strips off the `.png` suffix as well. So it will turn `/freddyfrog/some/place.png` into `place`.

Comment: What does mean `(flipped)`? Is it of any use?

Comment: It mean the same edge but starting at the other end - so one string represents the pixels along the right edge of an image starting at the top and going to the bottom, whilst `flipped` is the same set of pixels but starting at the bottom running to the top - that allows you to `flip` images over and around to match up.

Answer (score 1):

This one was easy, if one uses all the info available in the individual tile PNGs:

[image: QR code (solution)]

The QR reader says: http://www.oracle.com/javaone/index.html

It took me less than 3 minutes to come up with the solution -- mainly because I had to type the respective command with one hand while being on the phone at the same time....

How did you produce the tiles?

### Update

Now that @RCola has finally answered my question (*"How did you produce the tiles?"*), I'll reveal how I came up so fast with the correct QR code image.

I did not use an algorithm as he had asked for. I used a "side-channel" attack, by-passing any need to think about such an algorithm.

This side-channel used an "information leak" which was contained in the tile images provided in @RCola's ZIP file. This info is leaked when running a simple `identify` command. Here I run it not as a 'simple' command, but -- to make the leaked information more obvious -- as a command that forces a specific output format:

```
identify -format "%f :  %g\n" {1,2,3,4,5}*.png

  10297-13918-3702.png :  400x400+160+0
  11976-7751-26756.png :  400x400+80+0
  13789-10513-4721.png :  400x400+80+160
 13858-18007-13070.png :  400x400+240+0
  15816-4564-31665.png :  400x400+160+240
  16369-21469-8252.png :  400x400+320+80
  17636-24599-1877.png :  400x400+80+240
 18056-16294-30425.png :  400x400+80+320
 20021-11440-20836.png :  400x400+240+320
 20056-20936-29071.png :  400x400+0+240
  21875-14159-1067.png :  400x400+320+240
 22161-18187-20222.png :  400x400+240+80
  22806-3380-17484.png :  400x400+0+160
  24426-18830-5627.png :  400x400+320+160
 24658-20374-23042.png :  400x400+0+0
 26507-21853-11958.png :  400x400+240+240
 27206-10104-18226.png :  400x400+0+320
 28824-13023-24184.png :  400x400+160+80
 30261-16558-25650.png :  400x400+0+80
   31250-3578-9750.png :  400x400+320+0
  32078-14314-1511.png :  400x400+160+160
     4555-18116-29.png :  400x400+160+320
  5004-10810-17642.png :  400x400+320+320
  5167-27533-24066.png :  400x400+240+160
  5774-30645-16062.png :  400x400+80+80
```

(The same information would be contained in the output of `identify {1,2,3,4,5}*.png` -- it would just not jump out so obviously.)

What does this show? The `%g` percent-escape prints the *geometry* information about the canvas associated with the PNG tile:

1. `400x400` is the overall size of this tile's canvas. It is obvious, that this was the size of the original PNG representing the complete QR code.
2. `+X+Y` is the *offset* associated with this tile on the complete canvas.

Using this info makes it extremely easy to directly know which PNG tile has to be placed on which location of the puzzle:

- `+0+0` obviously has to go to the top left corner
- `+0+80` obviously goes just below that
- `+80+0` obviously goes just right of the top left corner
- ...and so on and so forth, until
- `+320+320` goes into bottom right corner

The OP could have avoided that side-channel info leak (which in this case gives the complete game away) by adding the `+repage` parameter to the IM command he used to produce the tiles.

In order to "repair" the leaky tiles he provided and produce more challenging ones I did this:

```
 mkdir challenge

 for i in {1,2,3,4,5}*.png; do
     convert $i +repage challenge/$i
 done
```

---

### Update 2

(In answer to the comment which despaired about the failure to "see" the info with the help of a hex editor...)

The same info as `identify` reveals could be obtained with the help of `exiftool` too (albeit in a less "accessible" form):

```
exiftool 11976-7751-26756.png  | grep -E '(Virtual Image|Width|Height|Offset)'
 Image Width                     : 80
 Image Height                    : 80
 Image Offset                    : 80, 0 (pixels)
 Virtual Image Width             : 400
 Virtual Image Height            : 400
```

Comment: Hahaha, good `hacking` skillz ) But it's not the answer to the question.

Comment: @RCola: I know it's not an answer to your question. But there is a much better, faster algorithm you could use, than the one you outlined in your question. (I didn't use it for *this* one.)

Comment: Are you referring to Mark Setchell's  algorithm?

Comment: @RCola: I hadn't seen Mark's answer until just a few minutes ago (before I updated my own answer).

Comment: @RCola: You didn't answer my question: "How did you produce the tiles?" (Because you made a mistake with that procedure, so it leaked more information through a "side channel" than you intended, which I used to come up with the fast first correct solution. So my solution came through a "side channel attack").

Comment: Sorry. It was super easy to split original something like that `convert crop 80x80 src.png tile%d.png`. Then I just gave each time random name.

Comment: Cannot reproduce `identify -format "%f :  %g\n" {1,2,3,4,5}*.png` on Win7. It gives **identify -format "  g\n" {1,2,3
,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}*.png
identify.exe: unable to open image `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,1
8,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}*.png': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
identify.exe: unable to open file `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}*.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3911.**

Comment: You should probably use a double \\ for each single \. Maybe also a double `%%` for each `%`. Also, the `{1,2,3,4,5}*.png` wildcard doesn't work on Windows. If you use ImageMagick on Windows, then please read (with a "grain of salt") and understand all of [http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/) before you return here.

Comment: Thanks, this worked `identify -format "%%f :  %%g\n" *`. But I still don't undestand how identify extracted this data. I opened png in HEX editor and have not found any of extracted data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better algorithm, which I scripted already:

1. From each tile, shave off a 1 pixel row or column from each edge, and output it to ImageMagick's special `*.text` format, using names which indicate their respective left/right or top/bottom edge origin.
2. Convert each such column/row, create the `md5sum` of its `*.txt` and sort these alphabetically.
3. Determine which MD5 sums are identical.
4. Determine from the identical MD5 sums the candidates which would fit at the respective border.

***Code snippet***

```
for i in {1,2,3,4,5}*.png; do
  convert ${i}[1x80+0+0]  +repage left---edge-${i/.png/.text}
  convert ${i}[1x80+79+0] +repage right--edge-${i/.png/.text}
  convert ${i}[80x1+0+0]  +repage top----edge-${i/.png/.text}
  convert ${i}[80x1+0+79] +repage bottom-edge-${i/.png/.text}
done
```

One example how such a text file may look is this:

```
cat right--edge-5167-27533-24066.text

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,80,255,gray
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,2: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,3: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,4: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,5: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,6: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,7: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,8: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,9: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,10: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,11: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,12: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,13: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,14: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,15: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,16: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,17: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,18: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,19: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,20: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,21: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,22: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,23: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,24: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,25: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,26: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,27: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,28: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,29: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,30: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,31: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,32: (255,255,255)  #FFFFFF  gray(255)
0,33: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,34: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,35: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,36: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,37: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,38: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,39: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,40: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,41: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,42: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,43: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,44: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,45: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,46: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,47: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,48: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,49: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,50: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,51: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,52: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,53: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,54: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,55: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,56: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,57: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,58: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,59: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,60: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,61: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,62: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,63: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,64: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,65: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,66: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,67: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,68: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,69: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,70: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,71: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,72: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,73: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,74: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,75: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,76: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,77: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,78: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,79: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
```

As you can see, it is a textual description for each pixel's color of the extracted column (where the pixel coordinates are given in the first field of each line of text). The first line indicates which color space is used.

***Sort MD5 sums alphabetically**

When sorting the MD5 sums of these text files alphabetically, it should be immediately obvious where there are identical pixel color rows and columns:

```
md5sum *.text | sort
```

***Results:***

(I manually added a few comments at the end of some lines.)

```
09c0670b59c03fb3d6f8116ee0fe35a2  bottom-edge-10297-13918-3702.text
09c0670b59c03fb3d6f8116ee0fe35a2  top----edge-28824-13023-24184.text
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  left---edge-20056-20936-29071.text  #left edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  left---edge-22806-3380-17484.text   #left edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  left---edge-24658-20374-23042.text  #left edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  left---edge-27206-10104-18226.text  #left edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  left---edge-30261-16558-25650.text  #left edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  right--edge-16369-21469-8252.text   #right edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  right--edge-21875-14159-1067.text   #right edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  right--edge-24426-18830-5627.text   #right edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  right--edge-31250-3578-9750.text    #right edge of QR
10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a  right--edge-5004-10810-17642.text   #right edge of QR
217c799ce772d99e11b7ba2a04f42bb7  bottom-edge-11976-7751-26756.text
217c799ce772d99e11b7ba2a04f42bb7  top----edge-5774-30645-16062.text
2c96cebc6cc175b54cae54f1a27771fa  bottom-edge-24426-18830-5627.text
2c96cebc6cc175b54cae54f1a27771fa  top----edge-21875-14159-1067.text
3088414b0fe1190bbd4ed9315d86a0ac  left---edge-13789-10513-4721.text
3088414b0fe1190bbd4ed9315d86a0ac  right--edge-22806-3380-17484.text
3755d45bb6ad21b70f545f39c5550eda  left---edge-17636-24599-1877.text
3755d45bb6ad21b70f545f39c5550eda  right--edge-20056-20936-29071.text
41fc32b4b70622b4aff7d9e81f81daad  left---edge-13858-18007-13070.text
41fc32b4b70622b4aff7d9e81f81daad  right--edge-10297-13918-3702.text
480bed740a716fa10593ba061c5b6df5  left---edge-5004-10810-17642.text
480bed740a716fa10593ba061c5b6df5  right--edge-20021-11440-20836.text
55cc4713ee13ebbeb5c2e212e430da94  bottom-edge-28824-13023-24184.text
55cc4713ee13ebbeb5c2e212e430da94  top----edge-32078-14314-1511.text
62fecd6971445d4176a842727767d3f7  left---edge-4555-18116-29.text
62fecd6971445d4176a842727767d3f7  right--edge-18056-16294-30425.text
69565761226f122f98267862108119a6  left---edge-21875-14159-1067.text
69565761226f122f98267862108119a6  right--edge-26507-21853-11958.text
72cec2b0a518c2cce7204188923d9f79  left---edge-26507-21853-11958.text
72cec2b0a518c2cce7204188923d9f79  right--edge-15816-4564-31665.text
7343348f1b10e47b33e0bde47b455c2b  left---edge-16369-21469-8252.text
7343348f1b10e47b33e0bde47b455c2b  right--edge-22161-18187-20222.text
7661c257d28e1916208ed2a70989e42d  bottom-edge-13789-10513-4721.text
7661c257d28e1916208ed2a70989e42d  top----edge-17636-24599-1877.text
7d2a0d7aae6dc017ffa7af7180b1c017  left---edge-5167-27533-24066.text
7d2a0d7aae6dc017ffa7af7180b1c017  right--edge-32078-14314-1511.text
85b744d1774cd4ebe50f0cc40d10b491  left---edge-18056-16294-30425.text
85b744d1774cd4ebe50f0cc40d10b491  right--edge-27206-10104-18226.text
88942ff37ce0e884d1995a6dd11708d6  left---edge-10297-13918-3702.text
88942ff37ce0e884d1995a6dd11708d6  right--edge-11976-7751-26756.text
9185daee4fdcea482c9fa805bba40346  bottom-edge-31250-3578-9750.text
9185daee4fdcea482c9fa805bba40346  top----edge-16369-21469-8252.text
9b8a7f18e4ebbc7249e5f26ac18190a8  left---edge-28824-13023-24184.text
9b8a7f18e4ebbc7249e5f26ac18190a8  right--edge-5774-30645-16062.text
9bd8f7a474229aefd988c4231f3b26f4  bottom-edge-21875-14159-1067.text
9bd8f7a474229aefd988c4231f3b26f4  top----edge-5004-10810-17642.text
a1778c1a468c122bf408a9c2bec9135c  bottom-edge-13858-18007-13070.text
a1778c1a468c122bf408a9c2bec9135c  top----edge-22161-18187-20222.text
a4f3eee0e523f1b343d292987da297b3  bottom-edge-20056-20936-29071.text
a4f3eee0e523f1b343d292987da297b3  bottom-edge-24658-20374-23042.text
a4f3eee0e523f1b343d292987da297b3  top----edge-27206-10104-18226.text
a4f3eee0e523f1b343d292987da297b3  top----edge-30261-16558-25650.text
af851da184ea6d6586c64aaefdc6875b  bottom-edge-22806-3380-17484.text
af851da184ea6d6586c64aaefdc6875b  top----edge-20056-20936-29071.text
b4047de9fb6458ebfde5b3a11b40241a  left---edge-5774-30645-16062.text
b4047de9fb6458ebfde5b3a11b40241a  right--edge-30261-16558-25650.text
b58fe9214967f6d2311e11cb0bf1acc4  left---edge-15816-4564-31665.text
b58fe9214967f6d2311e11cb0bf1acc4  right--edge-17636-24599-1877.text
bef4d7004da4f5de4ca5beeabc1222e8  bottom-edge-5774-30645-16062.text
bef4d7004da4f5de4ca5beeabc1222e8  top----edge-13789-10513-4721.text
c042d1cd3dfb339177e8da3c2907d58e  bottom-edge-15816-4564-31665.text
c042d1cd3dfb339177e8da3c2907d58e  top----edge-4555-18116-29.text
c5f38ebda77190495d77df1fb7002d1e  bottom-edge-32078-14314-1511.text
c5f38ebda77190495d77df1fb7002d1e  top----edge-15816-4564-31665.text
c61f738453fa3a86b52b2de5c0d43530  left---edge-20021-11440-20836.text
c61f738453fa3a86b52b2de5c0d43530  right--edge-4555-18116-29.text
c772762652d22cbf228e57f0dcf1a3b4  bottom-edge-22161-18187-20222.text
c772762652d22cbf228e57f0dcf1a3b4  top----edge-5167-27533-24066.text
cfaa399406e0be3d07297f23c684e7c3  left---edge-11976-7751-26756.text
cfaa399406e0be3d07297f23c684e7c3  left---edge-31250-3578-9750.text
cfaa399406e0be3d07297f23c684e7c3  right--edge-13858-18007-13070.text
cfaa399406e0be3d07297f23c684e7c3  right--edge-24658-20374-23042.text
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  bottom-edge-18056-16294-30425.text  #bottom edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  bottom-edge-20021-11440-20836.text  #bottom edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  bottom-edge-27206-10104-18226.text  #bottom edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  bottom-edge-4555-18116-29.text      #bottom edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  bottom-edge-5004-10810-17642.text   #bottom edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  top----edge-10297-13918-3702.text   #top edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  top----edge-11976-7751-26756.text   #top edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  top----edge-13858-18007-13070.text  #top edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  top----edge-24658-20374-23042.text  #top edge of QR
d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d  top----edge-31250-3578-9750.text    #top edge of QR
d71e7b561d2cc251c962a843daff53bb  bottom-edge-5167-27533-24066.text
d71e7b561d2cc251c962a843daff53bb  top----edge-26507-21853-11958.text
d7ffe4aaf744387e7fa9db32271247e0  bottom-edge-26507-21853-11958.text
d7ffe4aaf744387e7fa9db32271247e0  top----edge-20021-11440-20836.text
da2aa01201b3da20a970928bc2bdef36  bottom-edge-30261-16558-25650.text
da2aa01201b3da20a970928bc2bdef36  top----edge-22806-3380-17484.text
dd86f02cfc0e260463c75ae5b8709f33  bottom-edge-16369-21469-8252.text
dd86f02cfc0e260463c75ae5b8709f33  top----edge-24426-18830-5627.text
dfdaa88ebf33284ac0367f92060cd060  bottom-edge-17636-24599-1877.text
dfdaa88ebf33284ac0367f92060cd060  top----edge-18056-16294-30425.text
f8e2f384f2269e086dc00fb6ff0b3f41  left---edge-32078-14314-1511.text
f8e2f384f2269e086dc00fb6ff0b3f41  right--edge-13789-10513-4721.text
fa59372704f3b48912a33f3780e9dce7  left---edge-22161-18187-20222.text
fa59372704f3b48912a33f3780e9dce7  right--edge-28824-13023-24184.text
fff7e26c6f9852fcfa51e79d154dc58a  left---edge-24426-18830-5627.text
fff7e26c6f9852fcfa51e79d154dc58a  right--edge-5167-27533-24066.text
```

One can immediately identify the following pattern:

1. 10 identical MD5 sums of `d39c2a0c14c20b66b441d368c164171d`
2. 10 identical MD5 sums of `10be914aa8b6aaa8c0e35a4a93421f3a`
3. 20 pairs of identical MD5 sums for left/right edges
4. 20 pairs of identical MD5 sums for top/bottom edges

In the case of '1.' and '2.' it is easy to see that these are all-white edges, representing left/right/top/bottom pieces of the complete QR.

The rest of the matches, '3.' and '4.' make it easy to fit each individual tile to a left or right "partner" in a deterministic way.

---

### Update

I've not seen Mark's answer until now. But I see his approach is similar to mine.

I'm not willing to add my complete script to produce the final re-composed QR code though.

So if Mark's solution includes this, he should get the approvement for the correct answer.

Comment: In point 1. you determine if tiles' edges match by comparing only 2 rows with width of 1 pixel. As you see in this example formed with blocks of size 14x14px. Let's say 2 sides matches while using shaved off 1px line/column/row BUT the rule `formed with blocks of size 14x14px` is broken in some cases if it is **NOT** `formed with blocks of size 14x14px`. Your algorithm fails so the Mark's algorithm does.

Comment: @RCola: I don't get what you want to tell me with your comment. Can you delete it and try to re-phrase?

Comment: If it's not clear I can provide image which will be joined together using `1px approach` but in result will form invalid QR

Comment: @RCola: *"you determine if tiles' edges match by comparing only 2 rows with width of 1 pixel."* -- **No!** A *row* always is 80 pixels wide and 1 pixel high. A *column* is 1 pixel wide and 80 pixels high.

Comment: @RCola: My solution solves your posed problem with your provided example ZIP. I assume the same for Mark's. If you want to change or add some rules, do so.

Comment: @RCola: As long as **(a)** your original PNG is a valid QR code, **(b)** the PNG includes a white "quite" zone with the same width as one QR "pixel" **(c)** the QR code is sliced into *quadratic* tiles of identical sizes -- so long my general algorithmic approach should also work with ***all*** QR codes. If you trim off the quite zone, it will still work for all but the following QR-codes: Version 2, Version 8, Version 16, Version 26 and Version 38.

Comment: "quite" in above comment is mis-spelled. It should be "quiet".

Comment: http://www.utica.edu/student-blogs/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/The-Perfectionists-Guide-to-Results-Lo.jpg )))

Answer (score 0):

I understand about nothing of your explanations but for matching tiles it suffices to compare the pixels along the common edge. This is because the splits are made across the QR cells, not between them.

You can work filling the array row by row, every time trying all unused blocks until you find a match. Actually several matches could arise by coincidence, so it is advisable to continue the search even after a match has been found. This will lead to a recursive implementation.

The corners and their immediate neighbors are easier to place by hand. With a little scrutiny, you can also find the blocks with the timing pattern.

Comment: Are You saying that if splits would have been made between QR cells it would be impossible to narrow down solution?

Comment: @RCola: it would be much-much-much-much more difficult. And there may be various different solutions possible (depending on the specific puzzle), and you'd not necessarily be able to determine which one is correct.

Comment: @RCola: yes, as confirmed by KurtPfeifle, split between cells would have been catastrophic as you could have placed the blocks arbitrarily, leading to horrible combinatorial explosion. With the possibility of valid decodes of the QR with unintended reconstructions.