# image reconstruction from pieces

Tags: image-processing

I have a set of images which are all pieces of one or more bigger pictures.

[image: pieces]

These are the reconstructed images with the pieces
[image: reconstructed]

I would like to puzzle the pieces together with an algorithm/software. Before reconstruction i cant tell how many pictures are in the pieces, but i know that all pieces are relevant and complete to fulfill this task.
Have searched around but found nothing relevant (mostly tomography and relevant stuff), because i think i dont know the right terms to search for.

Can someone give me the right direction or eventually tell me which software (open-source preferred) can be used for this "problem"?

thanks

Comment: Please provide a couple of individual pieces.

Comment: sure, here we go, pieces for second row in reconstructed image :) http://workupload.com/file/5fAYY9J

Comment: I haven't looked too closely as I am busy at the moment, but I did something similar a while back... http://stackoverflow.com/a/27859253/2836621

Comment: I don't know if it helps but the images are exported from PDF files with https://poppler.freedesktop.org/. If there are are options to export them as one picture from the pdf please let me know.